# my app crashes when add values from fields into an NSDictionary

Tags: objective-c, ios, nsdictionary

i am developing an app where a user adds medicine name and number of times he should take it .. (the add view is presented as modal view).

when i NSlog the values populated from the user it seems to be okay when i try insert them to a dictionary the app crashes

```
NSString *name = [NSString stringWithString:[MedName_Field text]];
int times = [[times_Field text] intValue];

NSLog(@"%@ - %i",name,times); // <- Here it is OK.

 //create a dictionary 
NSDictionary *dic = [[NSDictionary alloc] init];
[dic setValue:name forKey:@"Name"]; // <- Crash!
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`NSDictionary` instances are **immutable** so you can't add/remove anything after they are created. You need to use mutable variant - NSMutableDictionary instead:

```
NSMutableDictionary *dic = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
[dic setValue:name forKey:@"Name"]; // <- No Crash! ;)
```

Answer (score 2):

[`NSDictionary`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/classes/nsdictionary_class/Reference/Reference.html) isn't mutable, so you can't create it then add keys and values to it.

Either create a mutable dictionary:

```
NSMutableDictionary *dic = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
[dic setValue:name forKey:@"Name"];
```

Or add you keys on `init` with `initWithObjects:forKeys:`:

```
NSDictionary *dic = [[NSDictionary alloc]
                     initWithObjects:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:name,nil]
                     forKeys:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Name",nil]];
```

But you can't add keys after this because the dictionary is immutable.